# parallel for using tbb library

Tags: c++, parallel-processing

If you have got a class and a parallel method like

```
    class A
    {
       void operator()(blocked_range<size_t>& r)
    const
   {
           double value = 0;
           for (size_t i = r.begin(); i != r.end(); ++i)
           {
               value = value + i;
           }

        std::cout << value;
       }
    }
```

and run that then value will be printed 1000 times also along with the loop. How can you run the loop only in parallel and use the result in other functions or other parallel loops that will follow? Since I need to use value in other functions but not wish to see it 1000 printed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a variable somewhere and passing it to your function by reference like so:

```
class A {
    void operator()( blocked_range<size_t>& r, double& answer ) {
        double value = 0;
        for (size_t i = r.begin(); i != r.end(); ++i) {
            value = value + i;
        }
        answer = value;
    }
}
```